# What does /etc/cron.daily/apt do?

Tags: debian, apt, cron

Could someone explain what the `apt` script is doing in `cron.daily` please?  I can't find any documentation on it.

**NOTE:** I'm trying to investigate a server-server communications issue which frequently occurs around midnight - and I want to rule out the cron dailies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on the configuration, it essentially does the following:

- `apt-get update` (update the package lists)
- `apt-get -y -d dist-upgrade` (download all upgradeable packages)
- `unattended-upgrade` (auto upgrade all upgradeable packages, requires the package `unattended-upgrades` to be installed)
- `apt-get -y autoclean` (autoclean package archive)